# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE How to configure

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I am working in a project with Django 1.8 and Python-3.4
I want install the mockups package for automate the data creation in my application.
I've installed this package with `pip install django-mockups` and `easy_install django-mockups`

I add the 'mockups' entry in my INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'suit',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mockups',
    'tracks',
    'albums',
    'artists', 
    'userprofiles',
)
```

I want to see in the django admin utility inside my console my commands available in relation with my packages installed, but at the end, I get the message of Note about of my environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and I cannot see the django-mockups package in the list

```
(venv)➜  myproject  django-admin help 

Type 'django-admin help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.

Available subcommands:

[django]
    check
    compilemessages
    createcachetable
    dbshell
    diffsettings
    dumpdata
    flush
    inspectdb
    loaddata
    makemessages
    makemigrations
    migrate
    runfcgi
    runserver
    shell
    showmigrations
    sql
    sqlall
    sqlclear
    sqlcustom
    sqldropindexes
    sqlflush
    sqlindexes
    sqlmigrate
    sqlsequencereset
    squashmigrations
    startapp
    startproject
    syncdb
    test
    testserver
    validate
Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).
```

(venv)➜  myproject

I check that django-mockups package is installed checking the following path directories, that in fact, exists.

```
 /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_mockups-0.4.8.dist-info` and
 /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups`
```

And `django-mockups` package is installed

```
(venv)➜  mockups  pip freeze
Django==1.8.2
django-mockups==0.4.8
django-suit==0.2.13
Pillow==2.9.0
wheel==0.24.0
(venv)➜  mockups
```

My `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is set of this way:
In the `manage.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "sfotipy.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

And in the wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And finally when I try start the django server, I get this output:

```
(venv)➜  myproject  ./manage.py runserver 
/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  return f(*args, **kwds)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mockups.factory import Factory
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups/factory.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mockups import generators
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups/generators.py", line 100, in <module>
    class StringGenerator(Generator):
  File "/home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups/generators.py", line 101, in StringGenerator
    coerce_type = unicode
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
(venv)➜  myproject
```

How to can I set correctly my DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable? 
Is this DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE configuration the origin of that mockups does not work?
Tanks a lot :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I find this [issue](https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups/issues/20) in github.

<del>Maybe</del> django-mockups is not support Python 3.

---

Python 3 change `unicode` to `str`, and the old `str` to `bytes`.

So if you run django-mockups with Python 3. `NameError` will be raised

As the traceback show, django-mockups is written in Python 2.

Comment: When I install django-mockups with python 3 I get this output: I wrote it in the issue entry  https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups/issues/20 but may be the reason ...

Comment: django-mockups does not support Python 3. A quick look at the code shows print statements without parentheses.

Comment: @neo_blackcap Of course.  I should try change this unicode line by str at the /home/bgarcial/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mockups/generators.py line still when this is the source code virtual environment? This is my doubt due to that virtual environment is made with python3.4

Comment: @BernardoGarcia No, that is the source code of django-mockups. What I mean is django-mockups is written in Python 2 instead of Python 3. So you run it with Python 3, you will get error.

Comment: @neo_blackcap Yeah! are you know some another libraries or packages similar to django-mockups for python 3?

Comment: @BernardoGarcia There are a lot of libraries that similar to django-mockups on Github, I am using [mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer) in my work

Comment: @neo_blackcap Interesting mixer